# Как компилятор С++ узнает по заголовочному файлу, что нужно подключить .cpp файл?

Tags: c++, header

есть 2 файла: `Element.cpp` и `Element.h`.

в `main.cpp` я подключаю `Element.h`. Но как компилятор узнает, когда и куда нужно подключить файл `Element.cpp`, в котором хранится реализация? Ведь его я нигде не прописываю.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Компилятор и не знает. При компиляции ему указываются какие именно `.срр` файлы компилировать, например

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

а во всех `.cpp` файлах нужно указывать необходимые заголовочные файлы.
Если вы работаете в IDE, то компилятору будут автоматически передаваться файлы исходного кода те, которые включены в проект.

Comment: о черт, вот это поворот) спасибо.

Comment: а если я хедер прописал а реализацию забыл подключить (ну допустим забыл подключить в настройках компилятора) то просто не скомпилируется мол "хедер то есть но реализации вот нет" ?

Comment: да, вы получите ошибку сборки `unresolved external symbol`

Comment: ха, как раз такую и получаю) вот зараза вот хитрости то. спасибо огромное. а я думал ест точка входа в приложение типа main.cpp и оно само все подключает как ему надо. а компановщик последовательность разруливает сам

Comment: Точка входа лишь определяет, откуда будет запускаться выполняемый файл. Если компилировать библиотеку (`.lib`, `.so` и т. п.) то компиляция и сборка будут проходить абсолютно так же, только функции `main` быть не должно т. к. библиотека будет включатся в запускаемый файл, и при её наличии обнаружатся 2 точки входа, что недопустимо.

Comment: @user2966664: Не, в те времена, когда изобретался C++, было принято взваливать всю скучную работу типа подключения всех нужных файлов на самого программиста. Более современные языки в этом отношении гуманнее.

Comment: @user2966664, если ответ Вам помог, пожалуйста, примите его. Для этого нужно нажать на галочку рядом с ответом.